# Difference between update method in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to figure out whether to use the **update** method in **serializer class** or in **view class** in Django Rest Framework when updating a user's data?

Also, I couldn't find anything related to this in much detail in the Rest Framework Documentation.
Can someone please help me understand it better or provide some resources for the same?

Comment: I've been there too. I can understand it after reading the code flow at [this link](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html).

I suggest reading from the `ModelViewSet` class for each of the basic methods i.e. `def list`, `def create`, `def update`, and `def destroy`. Then I hope you can find what you are confused about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depends upon whether you've to use it either in `serializers` or in `views`. but most of developers used in `views` with custom pre-define function method . for e.g-

```
class SnippetDetail(APIView):

   #Update a snippet instance.

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```